# Integrate $ \int \frac{x^2}{x+1} dx $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I integrate by changing variable or by parts?

$$ \int  \frac{x^2}{x+1} dx $$

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why not to use $x^2=(x^2-1)+1$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\frac{x^2}{x+1} = x-\frac{x}{x+1}$$ If you are integrating a ratio of polynomials where the numerator is of higher degree than the denominator, always try polynomial division.

Answer (score 2):

Changing variables as you ask, but there are better ways

Take $x=y-1$ so $\int \frac{x^2}{x+1} dx=\int \frac{y^2-2y+1}{y} dy=\int y dy + \int -2 dy + \int \frac{1}{y}$ so $\int \frac{x^2}{x+1} dx=\frac{y^2}{2}-2y+log(y)$
Subsitue again and you are done.